# Proof a function is injective - (intermediary step to proving the rationals are countable)

Tags: functions, solution-verification, rational-numbers

I am proving the rationals (greater than 0) are countable. I have to prove a function is injective and I just wanted another opinion on whether my proof is correct or if there is an even better method of proof.

I have the following function - *f : Q(greater than 0) -> Naturals*

*f(m/n) = 2^m 3^n* (where m and n are coprime)

I have to prove that this function is injective.
Proof:

For all m/n and m'/n' in Q (>0)
WTS: f(m/n) = f(m'/n') implies m/n = m'/n'

*f(m/n) = 2^m 3^n*

*f(m'/n') = 2^m' 3^n'*

Suppose m != m' and n != n' for a contradiction.

By the definition of injective functions we have:

*2^m 3^n = 2^m' 3^n'* which is equivalent to
*2^m 3^n (1- 2^(m'-m) 3^(n'-n)) = 0*

Since *a^b = 0* does not have a solution. We have that:

*2^(m'-m) 3^(n'-n) = 1*

Since 2 divides the LHS, it must divide the RHS so 2 divides 1. Which is a contradiction as n divides 1 is false for all n > 1. We can do something similar with 3 as well. So our assumption that n != n' and m != m' is incorrect. Yielding m = m' and n = n' as required.

Note: I have a feeling there is a far better way of showing this so if you have a better method please tell me :)

Comment: Just use unique prime factorization...

Comment: Please use mathjax. Otherwise its too hard to follow.

Comment: @PAM1499 yeah thats much better, don't know why I didn't use FTA right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problems here. You should not suppose that $m\ne m'$ **and** that $n\ne n'$; what you should suppose is that $m\ne m'$ **or** that $n\ne n'$.

And, after writing that $2^{m'-m}3^{n'-n}=1$, you act as if the LHS is a natural number, but it doesn't have to be.

You can simply say that $2^m3^n=2^{m'}3^{n'}\implies m=m'\wedge n=n'$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.